# android attributes are only used to present datatypes or.. is there something else it is good for

Tags: android

there is not a lot of material out there. But I am trying to understand how and why to use attributes.

Here is what I tried: I download and ran [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/create_custom_attributes_for_custom_component.htm) and all the attribute does is present a boolean data type, based on that, the app decided if it wanted to run a specific function. Is that all attributes are good for, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

> But I trying to understand how and why to use attributes.

Attributes are for configuring `View` objects in layout XML resources, as opposed to having to configure them in Java code.

> I download and ran this tutorial and all the attribute does is present a boolean data type

There are two custom attributes defined for that custom `View`, as you can see in the `res/values/attrs.xml` file.

> is that all attributes are good for... or am I missing something

In the example, there is a second attribute, `delimiter`, that is used separate the year, month, and day values in the `SimpleDateFormat`.

People who read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) will notice that there hundreds of attributes used on `View` and its subclasses, for a wide range of roles. Custom attributes applied to custom views can be used for those same sorts of roles.

Comment: I also downloaded and ran your tutorial colorMix. you have an attribute called 'color'  ., what exactly does that do ? and why did you decide to use it ?

Comment: why is it important to have configurations in xml code rather than java code ?

Comment: @jackshatck: "what exactly does that do ?" -- it sets the initial color to show in the `ColorMixer`. "and why did you decide to use it ?" -- so that developers could elect to set the initial color in the layout XML file. "why is it important to have configurations in xml code rather than java code ? " -- IMHO, simplicity and flexibility. However, "important" is a statement of opinion, and Stack Overflow is not well-suited for that sort of question.